# windows phone authenticated push with php - getting no response at all

Tags: php, curl, windows-phone-8, push-notification, ssl-certificate

Here is my php for the service

```
$r = curl_init();
curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_URL, $uri);
curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 

curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120);
curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 20);
curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

//curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, 'ssl.key'); 
//curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'ssl2.crt'); 
curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, 'ssl3.pem');  
//curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE, 'PEM');
//curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, 'mypassword');
//curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
//curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_SSLENGINE, 'x509');
//curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_SSLKEYTYPE, 'PEM'); 
curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $httpHeadersToast);
curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $toastMessage);
$output = curl_exec($r);
curl_close($r);
```

I've tried various combinations of the above code and the `$output` is simply empty on most or I get a 403 "Forbidden" depending on which commands I use.

I have my server through Dreamhost...using a signed comodo cert...when I go and view the cert, there is the "Certificate" then the "Key" then the "Intermediate Certificate".  The "Certificate" is the one that I have uploaded to my Windows Phone developer account and the "thumbprint" matches.

I know my Phone's push URI is legit because it has the "https....unthrottled..."

I had this working before as "unauthenticated" but I want to use my secure server.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `php` nor `curl`. Does `$output` return the HTTP response body? If so, it's no surprise it's empty. MPNS return all the response parameters in the headers.

Comment: @Eran, yes...$output is the response...and MPNS returned everything in that before when I was using the 'unauthenticated' method...**EDIT, sorry...yes, I am parsing the header out of the $output and it's empty.

Comment: Ok...looks like curl has been trying to tell me something all along. Using "$error = curl_error($r);", I see that it is having trouble with my certificates...back to the drawing board I guess...=(

Answer (score 1):

I had the same 403 issue with curl/php. I got authenticated push working by using my crt and key and CA file that contained both GoDaddy CA bundle (our crt is from GoDaddy) AND "full" CA bundle (/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt on Fedora) appended.

Also make sure your script has read permissions to all certificate files. Typically private keys are only readable by root.

Edit: Added exact CURL options related to authentication:

```
    curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, '2');
    curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, '1');
    curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_CAINFO,  $ca_file);
    curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $cert_file);
    curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, $key_file);
```

$ca_file contains the CA bundle mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I am using Dreamhost and I am just using the 'primary cert' and not the intermediate cert.  Should I bundle them all together into a single file?

Comment: Also, I did a chmod of 755 on my cert and my 'service.php'...how do I make sure the 'service.php' can read them properly?  I'm not a linux shell wiz.  =( Thanks again!

Comment: @iceman198 Add CA bundle with `CURLOPT_CAINFO` option. `chmod 755` could be enough or `chown` the file for apache (if php is run from apache). Depends on the host.